# How to tell if SQLite is frozen?

Tags: linux, freeze, sqlite

I have created a file with a list of approximately 8 million import statements to be imported into an SQLite database. I have been redirecting errors to a file. Every few thousand lines there is an error, which let me know the progress of the import. As of yesterday the import was at line 5 million, but as far as I can tell nothing new has happened. [The import process - `cat listofsqlstatements.sql| sqlite3 mydb.db 2>errors.txt` - is still running.]
The error log has not changed; 
the file size of the db seems unchanged (using `du database.db`); 
and an - `sqlite3 mydb.db "select distinct * from sometable"|wc -l` does not show any change.
However, looking at `htop` I see the import process has high CPU use. 
What might be going on? 
How might I determine this? 
Can I check to see what the last data imported to the DB was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strace -p` to attach to the `cat` process. See if it's still reading from the file.

By the way, if you're not doing your [import inside a transaction](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19), it will run several hundred times slower than it should.

Comment: So true. I've revised the code that generates the import statements. Now, I'll just use the sqlite3 .import with a csv file delimited by |.